# Executing code depending on parameter in controller

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

So I have this controller code, with dependency injection setup

```
private IManager manager

public Controller(IManager manager)
{
   this.manager = manager
}

Task async GetAsync(string appId)
{
   await manager.ProcessAsync(appId)
}
```

Depending on the appid information should be queried from subsystems, so instead of making 1 big manager with a huge switch/case block I would like to create a manager implementation for each subsystem.

What I thought I could do is making an abstract manager class from which the subsystem managers would derive

```
public interface IManager
{
  Task ProcessAsync(string appId)
}

public abstract class Manager : IManager
{
  public virtual Task ProcessAsync(string appId)
}

public class ManagerA : Manager
{
  public override Task ProcessAsync(string appId)
}

public class ManagerB : Manager
{
  public override Task ProcessAsync(string appId)
}
```

How can I setup the code (and dependency injection) so my controller calls the right manager depending on the appId parameter?
Kind of

```
Task async GetAsync(string appId)
{
   switch (appId)
   {
      case AppA: 
         managerA.ProcessAsync(appId)
         break;
      case AppB: 
         managerB.ProcessAsync(appId)
         break;
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely want to use a Factory or Provider for your manager. The factory or provider can produce the correct Manager based on the action parameters. Then you may not need to continue passing the `appId` around, since each Manager is written for a particular app.

```
private IManagerProvider managerProvider

public Controller(IManagerProvider managerProvider)
{
   this.managerProvider = managerProvider;
}

Task async GetAsync(string appId)
{
   IManager manager = managerProvider.GetForApp(appId);
   await manager.ProcessAsync(appId); // maybe appId isn't necessary here
}
```

```
class ManagerProvider : IManagerProvider
{
    public IManager GetForApp(string appId) => appId switch
    {
        AppA => managerA,
        AppB => managerB
    };
}
```